# Website performance measurement

Tags: performance, web-applications

I need a tool to measure a website's performance that's free and does not require any changes to be made to the code (jsp asp pages). All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

For performance measurement I recommend you [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/), it's a Firefox add-on integrated with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), it analyzes your web pages and tells you why they're slow based on the [rules for high performance web sites](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/index.html#rules).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIzkd.png)

Also with the Firebug Network Monitoring tab, you can see which resources are taking more time and bandwidth to download:

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/net.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) which will work for browsers other than Firefox. (But will not profile javascript code)

See [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250442(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers to this question focus on performance of a single user of the site from their browser's point of view.  If you want to test the performance of your server, for example, to see how many concurrent users you can support, you need to be looking at tools like [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).