# Measuring the performance of the website

Tags: java, spring, struts2, ibatis

I Have been working on a web based project which is made up of technologies like struts2,spring2.6 and ibatis with servlets , Now the issuse is that the outcome of this project is a website means on hitting the starting url its start but the website pages are too slow means to switch from one jsp to another it takes much time, Now I want to measure the performance and want to optimize it so that it can be a fast a little bit, Please advise which tools will help me to achieve this..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297777/website-performance-measurement

Comment: If you want to optimize your site you should look for *profiling* tools that could help you detect which parts or classes should be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org) for performance or load testing.

Within java you can try profiling. Your IDE like Eclipse should have some options.

Answer (score 0):

One tool you could use for benchmarking is [Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html). Else you may just open the network overview in Chrome  (CMD + alt + j for OS X) and see how fast each request is. With the Chrome network viewer you may see how fast pages load, images and so on. This is however client-side based and can't check individual jsp files.

Answer (score 0):

[JAMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/) and [JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) are my tool of choice for such cases.